# loop creates false amount of plots

Tags: r, loops, plot

I'm very new to R and alread exaustively have searched the internet for a solution and found nothing that would help me.

I have a problem regarding plots that are created out of a for-loop. I want to create six graphs in a 3x2 grid, where all graphs are displayed together and where each has the column label of the data as its heading. However it seems that R doesn't create 6 but twice the amount of graphs, whereas 6 of them have the wrong heading (Series R[,i] instead of DJINDUS for example).

My dataset (which is a matrix called "R") looks the following and has several thousand rows:

```
         DJINDUS       GSCITOT      NASCOMP       DJTRSPT       DJUTILS     PORTFOLIO
 [1,] -0.0051797207  0.0038918968 -0.014959142 -0.0100216161  0.0025465706 -0.0047444023
 [2,]  0.0103448153 -0.0023765810  0.013946279  0.0164086084  0.0073205395  0.0091287322
 [3,]  0.0038053079 -0.0131512085  0.004045313 -0.0046264989  0.0053159370 -0.0009222299
 [4,]  0.0234136525 -0.0107384963  0.013765670  0.0120004619  0.0099954557  0.0096873488
 [5,] -0.0019038671 -0.0064305092  0.006087090  0.0026823416  0.0046855706  0.0010241253
 [6,]  0.0103801289  0.0012181536  0.009976454  0.0081995006  0.0015569907  0.0062662457
 [7,] -0.0005007307  0.0075137168  0.004886162  0.0041719526 -0.0009155833  0.0030311035
 [8,]  0.0058533353  0.0066382973  0.003438548  0.0047356660  0.0011900949  0.0043711882
 [9,]  0.0058077604  0.0080331085  0.003620382  0.0058304700 -0.0024733215  0.0041636798
[10,] -0.0039335841  0.0120232095  0.006624884  0.0074794664 -0.0043200582  0.0035747834

par(mfcol=c(3,2))

for (i in 1:6){
  ACF.R <-acf(R[,i], lag.max=20, type="correlation", na.action = na.fail)
  header <- colnames(R)[i]
  plot(ACF.R, ci=0.95, type = "h", xlab = "Lag",
       ylab = "ACF", ci.type = "white", main = header)
}
```

This is how the (false) graphical output [looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjRPP.png)

[image]

Would you please so kind to check my code and tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `plot=FALSE` in your `acf` call:

```
for (i in 1:6){
  ACF.R <-acf(R[,i], lag.max=20, type="correlation", na.action = na.fail, 
              plot=FALSE)
  header <- colnames(R)[i]
  plot(ACF.R, ci=0.95, type = "h", xlab = "Lag",
       ylab = "ACF", ci.type = "white", main = header)
}
```

This should produce the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

By default, each `acf()` call prints a plot, too. Add `plot=FALSE` to prevent it from doing so:

```
labels <- c("DJINDUS","GSCITOT","NASCOMP","DJTRSPT","DJUTILS","PORTFOLIO")
R <- matrix(rnorm(10*length(labels)), nrow=10)
colnames(R) <- labels
par(mfcol=c(3,2))
for (i in 1:6) {
  ACF.R <-acf(R[,i], lag.max=20, type="correlation", na.action = na.fail, plot=FALSE)
  header <- colnames(R)[i]
  plot(ACF.R, ci=0.95, type = "h", xlab = "Lag", ylab = "ACF", ci.type = "white", main = header)
}
```